# Using CAST or CONVERT in CONTAINS - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to use the `CAST` or `CONVERT` functions in a SQL query like this :

```
SELECT *
FROM [SQL_BMS].[dbo].[GEID]
WHERE CONTAINS(CONVERT(nvarchar(max), NUID), 'titre')
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM [SQL_BMS].[dbo].[GEID]
WHERE CONTAINS(CAST(NUID as nvarchar(max)), 'titre')
```

but I'm getting errors:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'

or

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'as'

So how can I cast my `NUID` column from `Int` to `nvarchar`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? If NUID  is an integer how are you expecting that it is going to contain the string "titre"?

Comment: My previous comment was irrelevant. How you suppose to find some TEXT into INTEGER column??

Comment: @Martin Smith Because i will not use exclusivly Integer but date + text + ...

Comment: @EmmanuelG. CONTAINS is used with [full-text search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx). Full-text search could be used on column with data types: char, varchar, nchar, nvarchar, text, ntext, image, xml, or varbinary(max) and FILESTREAM.

Comment: @gofr1 I want to do a column concatenation for the contains that have multiples types: date, int, text, varchar,... and find a string inside the concatenation

Comment: @EmmanuelG. too long for comment so I add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187956.aspx) with `SCHEMABINDING`, with some `ID` and concatenated columns.

```
CREATE VIEW dbo.[view_GEID]  
WITH SCHEMABINDING  
AS  
SELECT  NUID, 
        Col1+Col2+CAST(Col3 as nvarchar(50))... as ConcatColumn
FROM dbo.GEID
```

Then create [full-text](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) index on that view. Then you can use [CONTAINS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx) for search purpose.

```
SELECT *
FROM [SQL_BMS].[dbo].[view_GEID]
WHERE CONTAINS(ConcatColumn, 'titre')
```

Another way is to concatenate all columns you need and use [LIKE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859.aspx), but it could lead to loss of performance.

```
SELECT *
FROM [SQL_BMS].[dbo].[GEID]
WHERE Col1+Col2+CAST(Col3 as nvarchar(50))... LIKE '%titre%'
```

Comment: thanks, yours was the greatest solution of all so you're the answer for me.

Comment: Great that it helped! ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM [SQL_BMS].[dbo].[GEID]
    WHERE CONTAINS(CONVERT(nvarchar(max),NUID), 'titre')
```